# Passing data to GatsbyJS template with different data structures but same named field

Tags: reactjs, jupyter-notebook, graphql, gatsby

I'm working with markdown files and Python notebooks in GatsbyJS, and I need a way to pass the edges from the two different file types into the component. Currently the error I get is that there is a duplicate declaration of "edges", so is there a way to distinguish the notebook edges from the markdown edges when setting the properties here:

```js
const {
  pathContext: { category },
  data: {
    allMarkdownRemark: { totalCount, edges },
    site: {
      siteMetadata: { facebook }
    },
    allJupyterNotebook: { edges }
  }
 } = props;
```

The goal is to set up category pages for both notebooks and markdown files, but you can see from the GraphQL query that the data is not structured the same (category is in metadata for notebooks vs. frontmatter for markdown. Any guidance to how to write this kind of property setting would be appreciated.  Full non-working template shown below.

```js
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import React from "react";

import { ThemeContext } from "../layouts";
import Article from "../components/Article";
import Headline from "../components/Article/Headline";
import List from "../components/List";

const CategoryTemplate = props => {
  const {
    pathContext: { category },
    data: {
      allMarkdownRemark: { totalCount, edges },
      site: {
        siteMetadata: { facebook }
      },
      allJupyterNotebook: { edges }
    }
  } = props;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ThemeContext.Consumer>
        {theme => (
          <Article theme={theme}>
            <header>
              <Headline theme={theme}>
                <span>Posts in category</span>
                {category}
              </Headline>
              <List edges={edges} theme={theme} />
            </header>
          </Article>
        )}
      </ThemeContext.Consumer>

    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

CategoryTemplate.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  pathContext: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default CategoryTemplate;

// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
export const categoryQuery = graphql`
  query NotebooksAndPostsByCategory($category: String) {
    allMarkdownRemark(
      limit: 1000
      sort: { fields: [fields___prefix], order: DESC }
      filter: { frontmatter: { category: { eq: $category } } }
    ) {
      totalCount
      edges {
        node {
          fields {
            slug
          }
          excerpt
          timeToRead
          frontmatter {
            title
            category
          }
        }
      }
    }
    allJupyterNotebook(
    filter: { metadata: { category: { eq: $category } } }
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          metadata {
            title
            category
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the `edges` new names:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names

In your example it would look something like:

```
const {
  pathContext: { category },
  data: {
    allMarkdownRemark: { totalCount, edges: markdownEdges },
    site: {
      siteMetadata: { facebook }
    },
    allJupyterNotebook: { edges: notebookEdges }
  }
 } = props;
```